# Tag filtering for product catalog

Tags: php, ajax, tags, product, catalog

Am looking for a name of php script/CMS with the following feature:

Assign tags instead putting them in a category for each item.

example below:
for example, i have 3 items:

```
item 1:
  mouse
  microsoft
  black
  usb

item 2:
  mouse
  genius
  white
  usb

item 3:
  keyboard
  genius
  black
  ps2
```

tag categories:

```
type
   keyboard
   mouse
color
   black
   white
brand
   microsoft
   genius
plug
   usb
   ps2
```

when i click on mouse i get item 1 and 2. then i click on white i get item 2 only.

there might be more tags like usb and ps2 that i dont want them to appear.

main thing is we will have many tags, so we put those tags into categories and search will be used upon this.

same thing we find mostly when we want to purchase products, but here tags is the main thing.

Think about it like this site, we put tags for each question and we select multiple tags to find good questions.

Answer (score 0):

Many CMS systems support tagging to some extent these days. Even if it doesn't natively support tagging you can normally find a plugin that does the trick.

Wordpress springs to mind although as a blog system it would take some work turning it into a catalogue. A quick Google reveals both Drupal and Joomla support tagging too.

However Magento looks like your best bet - http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-product-tags-work/